# file_put_contents not working on PHP versions 5.4 and higher

Tags: php, version, file-put-contents

The following code does not work on PHP version 5.4 and higher on my server due to deprecation. Changing PHP version to 5.3 or lower with MultiPHP Manager, however, works fine.

What should I do to the following code to make it work for updated versions?

```
    <?php
//blog.theonlytutorials.com
//author: agurchand

if($_POST){
//get the url
$url = $_POST['url'];

//add time to the current filename
$name = basename($url);
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
$name = $txt.time();
$name = $name.".".$ext;

//here is the actual code to get the file from the url and save it to the uploads folder
//get the file from the url using file_get_contents and put it into the folder using file_put_contents
$upload = file_put_contents("uploads/$name",file_get_contents($url));
//check success
if($upload)  echo "Success: <a href='uploads/".$name."' target='_blank'>Check Uploaded</a>"; else "please check your folder permission";
}
?>

<html>
<head><title>Theonlytutorials - Simple File Upload from URL Script!</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Theonlytutorials.com - Very Simple File Upload from URL Script!</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Your URL: <input type="text" name="url" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Failures of `file_put_contents()` are almost always due to permissions issues.

Comment: I set permission to 0777 but no effect. Files are downloading to server with name but only 0 bytes.

Comment: In php 5.3 everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you put data with `file_put_contents()` on one server (or xampp) and then retrieve the info with `file_get_contents()` on another server, the function may not work. I ran the code to put the data into the file and then read it back with `file_get_contents()`, and it worked. In other words, if it doesn't seem to be working, make sure you are reading from a file that you created on the same server.

Other than that, see other ideas about having correct settings in php.ini